# Unable to trigger function for testing using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-select

I am new to testing React, and I am attempting to test that HotelSelect.handleInputChange is called when a user changes the input value on the AsyncSelect component (connected by it's onInputChange callback).

**HotelSelect.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import HotelSearchApi from '../api/HotelSearchApi';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import './HotelSelect.css';

export default function HotelSelect({
  ...props
}) {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState({value: '', label: ''});

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelectValue({value: props.hotel.brand_code, label: props.hotel.brand_code});
  }, [props.hotel])

  function formatHotelList(hotels) {
    return hotels.map(function(hotel) {
      return {...hotel, ...{ value: hotel.brand_code, label: hotel.brand_code } }
    });
  }

  function handleInputChange(newTerm) {
    setSearchTerm(newTerm);
  }

  async function loadOptions() {
    let hotels =  await HotelSearchApi.search(searchTerm);
    return formatHotelList(hotels);
  }

  return (
    <AsyncSelect cacheOptions={true}
                 className="HotelSelect"
                 defaultInputValue={props.hotel.brand_code}
                 value={selectValue}
                 loadOptions={loadOptions}
                 onChange={props.changeHotel}
                 onInputChange={handleInputChange}/>
  )
};
```

**HotelSelect.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import HotelSelect from './HotelSelect';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { mount, shallow, render } from 'enzyme';

const hotel = {
  brand_code: '12345'
}

const searchData = {
  data: [
    {
      id: '123',
      type: 'hotel',
      attributes: {
        brand_code: '55555',
        name: 'A Hotel'
      }
    }
  ]
}

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const selector = renderer
    .create(<HotelSelect hotel={hotel} />)
    .toJSON();
  expect(selector).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('should update searchTerm as user changes input', () => {
  const myF = jest.fn();
  const selector = mount(<HotelSelect hotel={hotel} />);
  selector.handleInputChange = myF;

  let input = selector.find('input');
  input.simulate('change', { target: { value: '5' } });

  expect(myF).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

When I use console.log to inspect selector it looks like the mock function is attached:

```
  ● Console

    console.log src/components/HotelSelect.test.js:38
      ReactWrapper {
        handleInputChange: [Function: mockConstructor] {
          _isMockFunction: true,
          getMockImplementation: [Function],
          mock: [Getter/Setter],
          mockClear: [Function],
          mockReset: [Function],
          mockRestore: [Function],
          mockReturnValueOnce: [Function],
          mockResolvedValueOnce: [Function],
          mockRejectedValueOnce: [Function],
          mockReturnValue: [Function],
          mockResolvedValue: [Function],
          mockRejectedValue: [Function],
          mockImplementationOnce: [Function],
          mockImplementation: [Function],
          mockReturnThis: [Function],
          mockName: [Function],
          getMockName: [Function]
        }
      }
```

Unfortunately the function doesn't seem to get triggered though:

```
  ● should update searchTerm as user changes input

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      37 |   input.simulate('change', { target: { value: '5' } });
      38 |   console.log(selector);
    > 39 |   expect(myF).toHaveBeenCalled();
         |               ^
      40 | });
      41 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/HotelSelect.test.js:39:15)
```

I must not be triggering the onChange event on the input box, which should trigger the onInputChange callback on the AsyncSelect component.

I have read over a couple TDD postings online, the jest documentation, and at least 3 questions on Stackoverflow but I am still not able to figure this out.

Appreciate any help!

## FirstQuestion :)

UPDATE:
I changed the test to the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import HotelSearchApi from '../api/HotelSearchApi';
import HotelSelect from './HotelSelect';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { mount, shallow, render } from 'enzyme';

const hotel = {
  brand_code: '12345'
}

const searchData = {
  data: [
    {
      id: '123',
      type: 'hotel',
      attributes: {
        brand_code: '55555',
        name: 'A Hotel'
      }
    }
  ]
}

jest.mock('../api/HotelSearchApi');

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const selector = renderer
    .create(<HotelSelect hotel={hotel} />)
    .toJSON();
  expect(selector).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('should update searchTerm as user changes input', () => {
  const selector = mount(<HotelSelect hotel={hotel} />);

  let input = selector.find('input');
  expect(HotelSearchApi.search).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  input.simulate('change', { target: { value: '5' } });

  expect(HotelSearchApi.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('5');
});
```

But the change event doesn't seem to be updating the value in the input. The failing test message says it is receiving '12345' which is the initial value (hotel.brand_code):

```
  ● should update searchTerm as user changes input

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "5"
    Received: "12345"

    Number of calls: 1

      39 |   input.simulate('change', { target: { value: '5' } });
      40 | 
    > 41 |   expect(HotelSearchApi.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('5');
         |                                 ^
      42 | });
      43 | 

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/HotelSelect.test.js:41:33)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with with

```
  selector.handleInputChange = myF;
```

Actually you cannot mock some internal variable this way. If that was a method in class-based component you could do that as

```
HotelSelect.instance().handleInputChange = jest.fn();
```

but it'd be a bad move anyway. You know what? You actually don't need to mock internal method.

There is no value in checking what internal method has been called. You only need to ensure some external API has been finally called and with expected parameters:

```
import HotelSearchApi from '../api/HotelSearchApi';

jest.mock('../api/HotelSearchApi'); // automock

...
it('should update searchTerm as user changes input', () => {
  const selector = mount(<HotelSelect hotel={hotel} />);

  let input = selector.find('input');
  expect(HotelSearchApi.search).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  input.simulate('change', { target: { value: '5' } });

  expect(HotelSearchApi.search).toHaveBeenCalledWith('5');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @skyboyer! That strategy makes a lot of sense. I tried the changes and the search function does get called, but not with 5. It is getting called with the initial value of the input:  Details added to question.

Comment: probably your test found a bug :) without `AsyncSelect`'s code it's hard to say, but to me it looks like that component just calls `props.loadOptions()` inside on input event and at that moment that callback refers to old `searchTerm`. My guess: in the real app that component would behave like searching for previous value, one step behind.

Comment: Thanks again, I really appreciated the help!